# Making a very basic discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
import discord
import os
from datetime import date
import schedule
import time

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def job():
  channel = client.get_channel(831104043505549333)
  await channel.send('Time to do your job!')

schedule.every().day.at("17:00").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

client.run(os.getenv('Token'))
```

Hi everyone, im trying to make a discord bot for the very first time. I have never ever used python before so im a bit in the dark. I've done a lot of java/javascript though, so i do know some of the common functions and a good bit of the terminology. basically, I want this both to print out a specific message in my discord server at a specific time every day. As of right now though, I'm struggling to even get it online in the server. It has joined the server, but it isnt printing anything in the command prompt on replit (where im building the bot), much less sending any messages in the channel.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: there are tons of tutorials online on how to build python discord bots, I suggest you look at those and the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html)

Comment: `client.run` is never going to run, as it's behind an unbroken `while True` loop.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo oh okay, how should I close the while loop here? Any specific way or just close it generically? I'm not familiar with how exactly it works in python